# Access Printer to Print document in Salesforce using apex class

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am newbie to Sales force and I want to access my local printer to Print some document with apex class. I don't want use JavaScript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apex runs server side, on Salesforce servers.  It can't access your local printer.  Your browser can access your printer though.  In lightning or visualforce you can create a button to launch your browser's print function using

```
window.print();
```